# Look-up from library to task list

Tags: workflow, lookup-column

I'm having problem with field look-up from document library to task list. Task created automatically with workflow when I creating item in Library. Could you ple help me with this matter? Please refer to a screen below.

[image]

Comment: please help me on this matter

Answer (score 2):

Sabir - I'm assuming you have a task process in your workflow that deals with the task assignment and steps.  If you want to inject the value from a field in the task list item into the document library item that kicked off the workflow, you can do the following:

1. Open up the task process in the workflow and, under **Customization**, click **Change the behavior of a single task**.
2. in the step entitled **When a task completes** set a workflow variable to the value of the current task's ID (the task process below is named **Task (4)**) so that, on completion, the task ID is saved for use by the parent workflow.  You do this using the **Set Workflow Variable** action.

[image: getting the task id]

3. In the parent workflow, after the task process runs, insert a **Set Field in Current Item** action and set the field's value (I called it DataAA) in the Document Library to the DataAA field value from the associated task by setting the **Data Source** to **Association: Task List** and setting **Field from source** to DataAA (or whatever you are calling your source field).  In the **Find the List Item** group, set Field to **ID** and **Value** to the variable you set in the task process (I called mine 'taskid').

[image: Setting the value]

Then, when the assigned user completes the task, the data field in the document library item will be updated with the task's data field.

I picked up the idea for easy task reference by setting a workflow variable in the task process from Lin Zhang's blog. Specifically **`https://lyndzhang.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/customize-start-custom-task-process-in-sharepoint-designer-2010/`**.  You can do the same thing by looking up the item in the association task list using **Field = Workflow Item ID** and **Value = Current Item: ID** (this is how the lists are associated). But, since a workflow Item could have a one-to-many relationship to tasks, looking it up by Workflow Item ID could return more than one value per workflow item - possibly not the one you're looking for, depending on your task process.